# how to implement Appl ovin Native Ad in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, native-ads, applovin, flutter-method-channel

I am using Applovin SDk in my flutter app, Banner and Interstitial is working fine but native. I want you to help me implement the native add. Or share some sort of useful links.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to find a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use MREC ad in applovin flutter package banner size.

BannerAdSize.mrec

Comment: Thanks for your time. But I want media view that's why am working on Native Ads

Answer (score 0):

Done Java/kotlin side coding and call in flutter

Comment: Do you have or know of an example for accomplishing this?

Comment: no, I don't have it. right now